# Error using python osmnx module, unable to plot footprint AND streetnetwork

Tags: python, osmnx

I use the osmnx python module for drawing street networks (artistic purpose).
I'm ok with most of the  examples given on github execpt N10, to plot footprints and street networks on the same plot.

I started with pasting this code :

```
import osmnx as ox

ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
ox.__version__

# helper function to get one-square-mile street networks, building footprints, and plot them
def make_plot(place, point, network_type='drive', bldg_color='orange', dpi=40,dist=805, default_width=1, street_widths=None):
    gdf = ox.footprints.footprints_from_point(point=point, distance=dist)
    fig, ax = ox.plot_figure_ground(point=point, dist=dist, 
                                    network_type=network_type, 
                                    default_width=default_width,
                                    street_widths=street_widths,
                                    edge_color='black',
                                    save=False, show=False, close=True)
    fig,ax = ox.footprints.plot_footprints(gdf, fig=fig, ax=ax, color=bldg_color, set_bounds=False,
                                save=False, show=True, close=True, filename=place, dpi=dpi)

place = 'portland_buildings'
point = (45.517309, -122.682138)
make_plot(place, point)
```

I'm getting this error message :

```
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "pyimage2"
```

It seems to come from the arguments in the second `fig, ax` declaration (precisely it's the arguments fig=fig, ax=ax).

I use vscode with python 3.8.2 interpreter.

How can I fix this error?